# How to find out if RDS cluster is being utilized or sitting idle costing money?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Is there any way [Cloudwatch metrics/AWS API] to know if RDS cluster is being utilized for have been sitting idle. Active connections to it or anything similar to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudWatch provides the `DatabaseConnections` metric. I would start by graphing the *maximum* value, per-day, for the last several weeks. This will make a very clear demonstration of whether anything is connecting to the database. You do *not* want to aggregate at a smaller interval, or select average, because that would tend to hide actual connections.

Depending on how you configured the database, you might also have connection or query logging enabled. That would give you a good indication of the last time someone actually did anything.

On the chance that you're looking at an infrequently-accessed database, I recommend making a final snapshot before shutting it down.

Comment: how can you get instance details which are backing rds cluster?
Right now I am trying the following approach

``` final DescribeDBInstancesRequest request = new DescribeDBInstancesRequest();
final DescribeDBInstancesResult response = rds.describeDBInstances( request );
final List<DBInstance> dbInstances = response.getDBInstances();```

I know that we need to apply filter to request but not sure how to apply filter for db-cluster-id.

Comment: @KiranKadam - you should ask this as a separate question, showing your current code (and using code tags so that it's readable).

Answer (score 1):

Monitoring is an extensive topic, and it entirely depends on your workload. For someone low CPU usage would be fitting metric, for someone - low traffic.

Here's [the overview](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MonitoringOverview.html) of RDS monitoring and metrics so you can see for yourself.